# Prove that $q(x) : =\prod_\limits{i=0}^{n-1}(x-A[i])-\prod_\limits{i=0}^{n-1}(x-B[i])$ is only the null polynomial if $A$ is permuation of $B$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Given a numerical series $A$ where $A[i]$ represents the $i^{th}$ element of the numerical series $A$. And a second numerical series $B$, where $B[i]$ represents the $i^{th}$ element of the numerical series $B$.

$$q(x) : =\prod_\limits{i=0}^{n-1}(x-A[i])-\prod_\limits{i=0}^{n-1}(x-B[i])$$

Where n represents the amount of elements you want to look at of your numerical series. $n,x \in \mathbb N$

I suspect that $q(x)$ is the zero polynomial just when $A$ is a permutation of $b$ regarding $n$ elements. But I can't find a way to prove it. Is there one or am I wrong?

(So I'd like to prove that if $B$ is no permutation $A$, $q(x)$ can't be the null polynomial.)

Comment: Multiplication is commutative, and the second product is by construction just a reordering of the factors of the first product.

Comment: @LutzL I feel like an Idiot now... I guess sometimes you just think too complicated to find an easy solution. Thank you.

Comment: @LutzL However there is something more complicated to it. Can you also prove that if $B$ is no permutation of $A$, $q(x)$ can't be the null polynomial.

Comment: If $B$ is not a permutation of $A$, then one of the $A[i]$'s, say $A[i_0]$ is not among the $B[j]$'s. Then the left product vanishes at $x=A[i_0]$, but the right product is non-zero at $x=A[i_0]$. Therefore the difference it is not the null polynomial. This was assuming that there are no repetitions within either sequence. If that was not assumed (I couldn't tell), then first take out as many common factors as you can (actually that might be a good idea no matter what).

Answer (score 0):

For $i=0,...,n-1$ you have $q(A[i])=0$, as both products are zero. The coefficient of the leading term of both products is 1, thus the leading terms $x^n-x^n$ cancel leaving you with $\deg q\le n-1$. Now you have a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ that has at least $n$ roots, …